# Как скрыть панель навигации при любых операциях с Activity?

Tags: java, android

При создании новой *Activity*, у меня получается скрывать панель навигации следующим образом:

```
     decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
     int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
     decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
```

Но как только я нажимаю на экран, панель навигации опять появляется.

Я пробовал обрабатывать нажатие на экран, изменение видимости панели навигации, но при первом нажатии на экран, все равно панель появляется и при этом событие не обрабатывается. После второго нажатия, навигационная панель скрывается.

Вопрос: как можно сделать так (и можно ли вообще), чтобы после запуска приложения панель навигации не появлялась.

Comment: Панель навигации? вы про ActionBar?

Comment: там где располагаются кнопки "назад" "домой", часы, уровень заряда и т.д.

Answer (score 2):

Я нашел ответ на поставленный вопрос, но возможно он подойдет не всем. В моем случае это то что надо. С помощью ADB я зашел в устройство по пути /system/app/, там лежит файл SystemUI.apk, который и является программой реализующей системный интерфейс андроида. Что бы его безвозвратно не удалять, просто переименовал. Затем перегрузил устройство. ВАЖНО: перегружать устройство необходимо средствами ADB, иначе(кнопкой ресет) система считает что произошел сбой и файл SystemUI.apk будет опять восстановлен.