# Как программно скрыть панель навигации Android 4.4.2

Tags: android, android-studio

Как можно скрыть панель навигации в своем приложении?

Я разрабатываю приложение под определенное (одно) устройство (Android 4.4.2), на котором оно должно быть на весь экран, в котором своя навигация и пользователь не должен мочь выйти из этого приложения. Я нашел способ как скрыть статус бар `this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);`, но как поступить с панелью навигации не знаю.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Идеально было бы конечно вообще уничтожить эту панель, как сделал автор [этого вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/454499/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BB%D1%8E%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F%D1%85-%D1%81-activity)
Но на своем устройстве я не могу найти файл SystemUI.apk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообще-то это довольно подробно расписано в документации. Состояние которое вам нужно называется *Immersive Mode* - [фтыкаем сюда и изучаем](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive.html), вас должен конкретно интересовать флаг: `View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY`, с небольшим уточнением, нужен небольшой хэндлер, чтобы при действиях юзера перехватывать всплытие панели навигации и сразу же скрывать его, иначе он будет всплывать снова и снова.

Если нужен конкретный код, то [кусок валяется здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21724420/how-to-hide-navigation-bar-permanently-in-android-activity).

Copy-paste кода:

```
private int currentApiVersion;

@Override
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    currentApiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;

    final int flags = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY;

    // This work only for android 4.4+
    if(currentApiVersion >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
    {

        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(flags);

        // Code below is to handle presses of Volume up or Volume down.
        // Without this, after pressing volume buttons, the navigation bar will
        // show up and won't hide
        final View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
        decorView
            .setOnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener(new View.OnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener()
            {

                @Override
                public void onSystemUiVisibilityChange(int visibility)
                {
                    if((visibility & View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN) == 0)
                    {
                        decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(flags);
                    }
                }
            });
    }

}


@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus)
{
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    if(currentApiVersion >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT && hasFocus)
    {
        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо. Да, я этот момент уже изучил. Меня волновало то, что эта панель появляется каждый раз. Я думал, что есть более цевилизованый способ, чтобы не использовать обработчик и не вызвать это действие снова и снова.

Comment: **Barmaley**, вы не могли бы посоветовать на что лучше повесить обработчик, который будет `getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility( `... ? То что в примере приведено повешено на смену фокуса, но все равно, проведя пальцем сверху или снизу появляются полупрозрачные панели. Вешать на тап главного view лайаута?

Comment: Да хз... здесь надо разбираться и экспериментировать с живым девайсом и IDE на руках. Эта задача, ИМХО явно выходит за пределы телеграфного стиля форума

Answer (score 1):

```
View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
```

https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/navigation.html